# Forms dropdown select option - show text, submit ID number in querystring

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

In this docs example, the option name is the value submitted in the query string: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls

```
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>Example option that can be a really long string</option>
      <option>Another option that can be a duplicate of another string but with a different ID</option>
      <option>Another option that can be a duplicate of another string but with a different ID</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

Instead of this primitive hard-coding, I would like for the form to have the ID number of the option, and render for the user the verbose text that represents that option:

```
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>
        1
        <verbose>Example option that can be a really long string</verbose>
      </option>
      <option>
        2
        <verbose>Another option that can be a duplicate of another string but with a different ID</verbose>
      </option>
      <option>
        3
        <verbose>Another option that can be a duplicate of another string but with a different ID</verbose>
      </option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

This way, the query string will have ID numbers, there won't be duplicate short-circuiting in the backend, and it'll be faster because the ID is indexed.

How can this be accomplished, what is the proper syntax for the `<verbose>` pseudocode tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag. Example:

```
<option value="1">Example option that can be a really long string</option>
```

Comment: Ohhh, that was easy. Thank you! (I must wait 8 mins to accept your answer)